# Mongo Authentication Error When Connecting to MMS ReplicaSet

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-mms

I deployed  and manage my MongoDB instances on the server using MongoDB Management Service (MMS) and I have deployed a replica set. I have also made sure that I added a user with the required permissions in the "Authorisation & Users" tab as shown in the image below.

[image: Authorisation & Users]

When I log into my server and run the command to check if the user has been added it shows that they have been authenticated because it returns 1.

```
$ use admin
$ db.auth('mbdb', 'xxxx')
$ 1
```

I have a node application that connects to mongodb using mongoose and this is the url format that I use to connect:

```
'url' : 'mongodb://mbdb:xxxx@localhost:27000/dbprod?replicaSet=ProdSet'
```

The issue that I am having is that when I start the Node application I get this error:

```
> mobile-bulletin-node@0.0.1 start /var/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d81f9c89b9a85a90
> node ./bin/www

{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

/var/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d81f9c89b9a85a90/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:246
    throw message;      
          ^
MongoError: auth failed
at Object.toError (/var/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d81f9c89b9a85a90/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:114:11)
at /var/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d81f9c89b9a85a90/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1156:31
at /var/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d81f9c89b9a85a90/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1890:9
at Server.Base._callHandler (/var/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d81f9c89b9a85a90/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:448:41)
at /var/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d81f9c89b9a85a90/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:481:18
at MongoReply.parseBody (/var/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d81f9c89b9a85a90/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
at null.<anonymous> (/var/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d81f9c89b9a85a90/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:439:20)
at emit (events.js:95:17)
at null.<anonymous> (/var/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d81f9c89b9a85a90/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:201:13)
at emit (events.js:98:17)
```

I have also attached my requested logs from the server that retrieved from MMS. I can see an authentication error but all the changes that I make don't seem to alter this error.

```
2015-03-11T04:04:00.183-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 159.8.163.164:42476 #6051 (6 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:04:00.194-0500 I ACCESS   [conn6051] Successfully authenticated as principal mms-automation on admin
2015-03-11T04:04:00.697-0500 I NETWORK  [conn6049] end connection 159.8.163.164:42462 (5 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:04:00.697-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 159.8.163.164:42477 #6052 (6 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:04:00.707-0500 I ACCESS   [conn6052] Successfully authenticated as principal __system on local
2015-03-11T04:04:03.158-0500 I ACCESS   [conn19] Successfully authenticated as principal mms-monitoring-agent on admin
2015-03-11T04:04:04.695-0500 I NETWORK  [conn6050] end connection 159.8.163.164:42468 (5 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:04:04.695-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 159.8.163.164:42486 #6053 (6 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:04:04.705-0500 I ACCESS   [conn6053] Successfully authenticated as principal __system on local
2015-03-11T04:04:05.184-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 159.8.163.164:42487 #6054 (7 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:04:25.811-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49873 #6055 (8 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:04:25.811-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49874 #6056 (9 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:04:25.812-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49875 #6057 (10 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:04:25.812-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49876 #6058 (11 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:04:25.812-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49877 #6059 (12 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:04:25.818-0500 I ACCESS   [conn6055]  authenticate db: dbprod { authenticate: 1, user: "mbdb", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-03-11T04:04:25.818-0500 I ACCESS   [conn6056]  authenticate db: dbprod { authenticate: 1, user: "mbdb", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-03-11T04:04:25.819-0500 I ACCESS   [conn6055] Failed to authenticate mbdb@dbprod with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-03-11T04:04:25.819-0500 I ACCESS   [conn6057]  authenticate db: dbprod { authenticate: 1, user: "mbdb", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-03-11T04:04:25.819-0500 I ACCESS   [conn6058]  authenticate db: dbprod { authenticate: 1, user: "mbdb", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-03-11T04:04:25.819-0500 I ACCESS   [conn6056] Failed to authenticate mbdb@dbprod with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-03-11T04:04:25.819-0500 I ACCESS   [conn6059]  authenticate db: dbprod { authenticate: 1, user: "mbdb", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-03-11T04:04:25.819-0500 I ACCESS   [conn6057] Failed to authenticate mbdb@dbprod with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-03-11T04:04:25.819-0500 I ACCESS   [conn6058] Failed to authenticate mbdb@dbprod with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-03-11T04:04:25.819-0500 I ACCESS   [conn6059] Failed to authenticate mbdb@dbprod with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-03-11T04:04:25.823-0500 I NETWORK  [conn6059] end connection 127.0.0.1:49877 (11 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:04:25.823-0500 I NETWORK  [conn6058] end connection 127.0.0.1:49876 (11 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:04:25.823-0500 I NETWORK  [conn6056] end connection 127.0.0.1:49874 (11 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:04:25.823-0500 I NETWORK  [conn6057] end connection 127.0.0.1:49875 (11 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:04:25.823-0500 I NETWORK  [conn6055] end connection 127.0.0.1:49873 (7 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:04:30.710-0500 I NETWORK  [conn6052] end connection 159.8.163.164:42477 (6 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:04:30.710-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 159.8.163.164:42495 #6060 (7 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:04:30.720-0500 I ACCESS   [conn6060] Successfully authenticated as principal __system on local
2015-03-11T04:04:34.707-0500 I NETWORK  [conn6053] end connection 159.8.163.164:42486 (6 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:04:34.707-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 159.8.163.164:42501 #6061 (7 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:04:34.717-0500 I ACCESS   [conn6061] Successfully authenticated as principal __system on local
2015-03-11T04:04:54.412-0500 I ACCESS   [conn19] Successfully authenticated as principal mms-monitoring-agent on admin
2015-03-11T04:04:54.414-0500 I QUERY    [conn19] assertion 13 not authorized for query on local.oplog.rs ns:local.oplog.rs query:{ $query: {}, $orderby: { $natural: 1 } }
2015-03-11T04:04:54.414-0500 I QUERY    [conn19]  ntoskip:0 ntoreturn:-1
2015-03-11T04:04:54.414-0500 I QUERY    [conn19] assertion 13 not authorized for query on local.oplog.rs ns:local.oplog.rs query:{ $query: {}, $orderby: { $natural: -1 } }
2015-03-11T04:04:54.414-0500 I QUERY    [conn19]  ntoskip:0 ntoreturn:-1
2015-03-11T04:05:00.724-0500 I NETWORK  [conn6060] end connection 159.8.163.164:42495 (6 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:05:00.724-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 159.8.163.164:42512 #6062 (7 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:05:00.734-0500 I ACCESS   [conn6062] Successfully authenticated as principal __system on local
2015-03-11T04:05:04.718-0500 I NETWORK  [conn6061] end connection 159.8.163.164:42501 (6 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:05:04.718-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 159.8.163.164:42517 #6063 (7 connections now open)
2015-03-11T04:05:04.728-0500 I ACCESS   [conn6063] Successfully authenticated as principal __system on local
```

I have deployed and connected to a mongodb database with an instance that I was managing myself without mms so I have a feeling that I am missing or have left out to allow me to connect to a mongodb instance managed by mms.

My automation agent, backup agent and monitoring agent are healthy too.

Comment: Can I get some community input here please? MongoDB MMS issues are "clearly" not a programming issue for what StackOverflow is now intended for given the site revamp of StackExchange sites. Where do MMS questions live? on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) related to database monitoring tools? Or [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) relating to professional server infrastructure? I'll start a chat thread for a vote if needed. But "leave it here because I want by SO points for my answer" is not a response. This doesn't belong here. Guide the OP to the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I finally got this working after almost pulling my hair out. The first thing I did was made sure that all my node modules were up to date by running

```
$ npm update
$ npm install
```

Once that was complete I modified my connection url to include the urls to my other mongo instances in the replica set. I did this because according to the mongodb documentation one needs to specify the other nodes in order to connect to a replica set or else a standalone instance will be created.

To complete my uri string I added the actual authentication database where my user credentials are stored. So in the end my connection uri looked like this:

```
'url' : 'mongodb://mbdb:xxxx@localhost:27000,localhost:27001,localhost:27002/dbprod?replicaSet=ProdSet&authSource=admin'
```